# Is there any property of vector that is invariant under absolute value of its elements?

Tags: vectors

If I take an absolute value of all elements of a vector, what properties would be invariant? Will it be a completely different vector since we cannot map back to the original vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length stays the same.  (both the number of elements and the geometric length).
The absolute value of each element stays the same.
The angle between the vector and any axis ( related to the direction cosines)  stays the same.